# Implement threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have multiple sources from where I am importing the list of articles. Below is the implementation. However, the improvement could be to run threads simultaneously for the same sources.

```
class Importer
  def init

    t1 = Thread.new(get_Articles('url1',
                                 'RSS',
                                 nil))
    t2 = Thread.new(get_Articles('url2',
                                 'RSS',
                                 nil)
    t1.join
    t2.join

  end
  def get_Articles(source_url, source_type, source_key)

    articles = Article.new
    if source_type == 'RSS' then
      ... 
    elsif source_type == 'JSON' then
      ...    
  end
end
```

I have implemented thread sort of. But I am not sure if I am doing the way it should be done in Ruby. Could somebody please advice me on this? On running above I get error - `must be called with a block` on `Thread.new(get_Articles('url1',`

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much correct. Gems like [`parallel`](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) might make it a bit prettier, but that's the idea.

Comment: @Amadan -  My implementation gives me error. I have updated my post now.

Comment: Right, as Martin says, wrong braces.

Comment: @Amadan -  
I get SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."title" = 'Among the paddocks and grazing cattle, the POWs called this place home' LIMIT 1 error. Added timeout: 10000 in database.yml under production. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Concurrent writing is not something SQLite3 handles well. Move to another database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation for Thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html) we see that `Thread.new` should be called with a block. That is, use curly braces instead of round parentheses:

```
t1 = Thread.new { get_Articles('url1', 'RSS', nil) }
t2 = Thread.new { get_Articles('url2', 'RSS', nil) }
```

Your original code runs `get_Articles` even before calling `Thread.new`, trying to pass the return value, which is not a block.

Comment: I get SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."title" = 'Among the paddocks and grazing cattle, the POWs called this place home' LIMIT 1 error. Added   timeout: 10000 in database.yml under production. Still the issue persists.

Comment: @coder05, Well, then just delete your question again.  No help from me, that's for sure.